# Unable to perform a Git Commit in Eclipse due to Russian characters

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using Git through Eclipse, and all has been fine, until recently. 
One of my colleagues has introduced new NPM modules. One of those modules contains a program with a Russian language name.

Specifically:

```
ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/archiver/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/isbinaryfile/tests/fixtures/03_Руководство_по_эксплуатации.rst
```

causes the issue:

```
Committing failed
An internal error occurred
Malformed input or input contains unmappable chacraters (sic)
```

My colleague tells me that it works in his NetBeans so it is not a problem.

Is there a workaround for Eclipse ?

Comment: As a workaround you can rename that file to use latin alphabet.

Comment: @Zloj, technically that might be a workaround but it's a very poor one, especially in 2015. It would be much better to have some way of making this work without having to rename the file.

Comment: @Chris just a suggestion. I guess there's no need to enumerate the advantages of using standard latin letters to name files. But, of course you have a good point here.

Comment: @Zloj, fair. It _is_ always nice to know what all the options are. It might be more difficult do implement your suggestion in the context of Git, though, assuming the file has some history. Having to retroactively rename it through its entire history would be very disruptive. (I don't actually know if this would be required.)

Comment: @Michal, yes that does look like a duplicate. I clearly searched with the wrong terms ! I will check when I am back in the office on Monday. Thank you

Comment: Chris & Zloj, renaming the original files is not very easy in this context, so I will try the link suggested by Michal